# Simplicial homology: chain group with basis open n-simplices vs. chain group with basis closed n-simplices

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

In his Algebraic Topology book, Hatcher defines the chain groups for simplicial homology as free abelian groups with basis the open $n$-simplices of some simplicial complex X.
Is there any benefit/difference by using *open* $n$-simplices in comparison to using *closed* $n$-simplices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the restriction to open $n$-simplices is just to remove any potential ambiguity from the fact that closed $n$-simplices may overlap, while their interiors do not.